# mySQL, how do I join 2 queries together?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, phpmyadmin

I simply have 2 queries:

Query 1:

```
SELECT orderID, paid, orderPrice, orderDate, payDate, Orders.customerID, Customers.cusName, Customers.cusEmail, Customers.totalOrderVolume, sum(orderPrice)
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers
ON Orders.customerID=Customers.customerID
WHERE paid = 1
GROUP BY customerID
```

Query2:

```
SELECT count(*) "numberTest"
FROM Orders
GROUP BY customerID
```

I do I join them together into 1 output table when they run, so as you can see the first query has 10 columns and the other 1 column, how do I add the 1 column from the second query to the first query so the output is one table with the 1 column added to the end so the output table has 11 columns when I run it.

Thanks in advance, I have been spending hours trying to figure this out, I am an SQL beginner, I just can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your first query looks very confused.  You seem to want the sum of the order price for each customer, but you also are selecting individual columns.  Some sample input and output data would be helpful.

Comment: The order table contains all the orders with each record a customer ID with it. I want to basically identify the high spenders, I want to calculate the sum of the order price accosiated with each customer. So for example in the order table there is an order of price 2 and 3 and both of those has the same customer ID of for example 10, the first query will out put 5 with the customer ID with all the other fields.

Comment: New versions of MySQL will not allow your first query. If you group, all selected rows needs to be aggregates. In your case, for example orderID is not a distinct match, as a bunch of orders will be grouped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT A.orderID, A.paid, A.orderPrice, A.orderDate, A.payDate, A.customerID, A.cusName, A.cusEmail, A.totalOrderVolume,A.sum,B.numberTest
FROM
(SELECT orderID, paid, orderPrice, orderDate, payDate, Orders.customerID as customerID, Customers.cusName, Customers.cusEmail, Customers.totalOrderVolume, sum(orderPrice) as sum FROM Orders INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.customerID=Customers.customerID WHERE paid = 1 GROUP BY customerID) as A
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT Orders.customerID as customerID, count(*) as numberTest FROM Orders GROUP BY customerID) as B
ON A.customerID = B.customerID

** I think customerID will be common to both the table.

Comment: OMG, you are the best! That is exactly what I am looking for!! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT A.orderID, A.paid, A.orderPrice, A.orderDate, A.payDate, A.customerID, A.cusName, A.cusEmail, A.totalOrderVolume,A.sum,B.numberTest FROM (SELECT orderID, paid, orderPrice, orderDate, payDate, Orders.customerID as customerID, Customers.cusName, Customers.cusEmail, Customers.totalOrderVolume, sum(orderPrice) as sum FROM Orders INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.customerID=Customers.customerID WHERE paid = 1 GROUP BY customerID) as A INNER JOIN (SELECT Orders.customerID as customerID, count(*) as numberTest FROM Orders GROUP BY customerID) as B ON A.customerID = B.customerID

Answer (score -1):

It's not clear from your question what the desired purpose from the two queries are, and how they are related, but this would do as you ask in your question.

```
SELECT 
    orderID,
    paid,
    orderPrice,
    orderDate,
    payDate,
    Orders.customerID,
    Customers.cusName,
    Customers.cusEmail,
    Customers.totalOrderVolume,
    sum(orderPrice),
    count(*) as `numberTest`
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers
ON Orders.customerID=Customers.customerID
WHERE paid = 1
GROUP BY customerID
```

Comment: Not coming up with the correct numbers, but the previous answer was correct. Thanks anyway.